# Confusion about scipy.fft function

Tags: python, audio, scipy, fft

I have an audio sample, which is sampled at **22k Hz** and total samples = 660k , as the duration is 30 seconds. (22k*30 = 660k)

When I plot the fft of the complete sample, I get a symmetric graph with 660k x values, and corresponding y values as shown: [image]

This seems to read as the sound sample has a maximum of 330k Hz frequency, (I have some idea that it repeats after half of the fft transform because of negative and positive frequencies having same values). If I adjust the length the sound sample, the maximum frequency of fft graph changes accordingly 
(length/2 -> max freq/2), 
[image]
which shouldn't happen as frequency is independent of length of sample.

Any advice? I am unable to grasp this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you compute the FFT of audio (or any data) of length *N* at a sampling rate *fs* the result will be an array, *Y*,  of *N* complex numbers where

magnitude(*Y(n)*) = amplitude at frequency **(n * *fs*)/N** Hz.

Where n = 0,1,2,...N.

meaning that Y contains the information on frequencies from 0 to *fs* (In some softwares like matlab the range returned is from -fs/2 to fs/2 instead).

In your case *fs* = 22000Hz , *N* = 660000 so

magnitude(*Y(n)*) = amplitude at frequency **(n * 22000)/660000** Hz ; n = 0,1,2,...660000.

So you x-axis should run from 0Hz to 22000Hz and not from 0 to 660000.

Comment: Right, thats what I think, that altering the sample size should not change the fft, as it samples upto a particular frequency limit (sampling rate). I will run a similar code in MATLAB and comment here then.

Comment: Changing the number of samples did not change the spectrum that much (as expected) the problem is that you are not plotting properly, you are plotting Amplitude vs Sample Index instead of Amplitude vs Frequency.The number of samples should not affect the range of the x-axis at all.

Comment: You don't need to go to matlab, I was giving you an example of a software that returns a different range, I should have not included that line as it seems to have caused a bit of confusion.

Comment: You can use [`np.fft.fftfreq`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fft.fftfreq.html) to create an array of frequencies from the number of samples and the sampling spacing.Using that for the X axis of both cases should give almost identical results (it already does, if you ignore the X axis values).

Comment: @KillaKem yes, i see now. The fft is calculated wrt no of samples by the function. Saw a Matlab code that justified that. Thanks

Comment: @Jaime: Thanks for the suggestion. I saw a tutorial and got confused as they used the fft function.